# How to remove default validation from login and registration form in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, jquery, form-validation

I want to remove default validation from login and registration form and add my custom validation in magento2.2.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove validation from Login page:**
Copy **login.phtml** from below path:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml

to your theme location:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml

and remove the below code from the form:
**data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'**

Also remove the data-validate from the every fields of that form.

Now you can add your custom validation according to your requirement.

**Remove validation from Registration page:**
Copy **register.phtml** from below path:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

to your theme location:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

and remove the below code from the form:
**data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'**

Also remove the data-validate from the every fields of that form.

Now you can add your custom validation according to your requirement.

Comment: Not working. I have already tried this.

Comment: I have checked it in local system and its working fine for me. Can you check if some module extended that file.

Comment: Now it is working. but after submitting my login form, the form is just being loaded. It is not logging in.

Comment: It is showing error message as 
"A login and a password are required."

Comment: Yes for this you need remove server side validation as well.

Comment: Just a small mistake from my side. I have changed the default name for the email and password. so that's why it was not working.

Comment: Any way your your solution was helpful to me. thanks.

Comment: You welcome. Happy coding.